# A simple problem about a Rule example

Tags: pattern-matching, rule

The documentation says that "[`Rule`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rule.html) *represents a rule that transforms lhs to rhs*" and gives the following example:

```
{x, x^2, x^3, a, b} /. x^n_ -> f[n]

(*{x, f[2], f[3], a, b}*)
```

I suppose, however, it should have given `{f[1], f[2], f[3], a, b}` and further tried a more explicit specification:

```
{x^1, x^2, x^3, a, b} /. x^n_ -> f[n]
```

As you may see, the output remains unchanged! What is the explanation for the result for the first item?

Comment: Can you provide a link to the documentation page with the example (by [editing your question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/posts/206139/edit), not here in comments)? For instance, for the text "The documentation says" (use Ctrl + L).

Comment: @PeterMortensen I added the link. BTW thanks for showing the shortcut.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Pattern matching is performed based on the form of an expression, not its (mathematical) meaning. Using jargon, pattern matching is performed syntactically, not semantically.

Specifically, here `x^1` is evaluated/simplified first to be `x`. The latter no longer has the form of "one thing raised to the power of another thing", so it will not be matched when applied the rule afterward.

Consequently, if you want the first one to be matched, you can stop it from evaluation by using [`Hold`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Hold.html) or [`HoldForm`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldForm.html) and [`ReleaseHold`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReleaseHold.html) in the end.

```
{HoldForm[x^1], x^2, x^3, a, b} /. x^n_ -> f[n] // ReleaseHold
```

> ```
> {f[1], f[2], f[3], a, b}
> ```

To see the function of `ReleaseHold`, evaluate

```
{HoldForm[x^1], x^2, x^3, a, b} /. x^n_ -> f[n] // InputForm
```

and you obtain

> ```
> {HoldForm[f[1]], f[2], f[3], a, b}
> ```

You see that `HoldForm` is still there, but usually in the [`OutputForm`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/OutputForm.html) it is invisible and `ReleaseHold` can remove it.

---

Another more concise way is to use [`Default`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Default.html) in the pattern (the dot following the underscore):

```
{x, x^2, x^3, a, b} /. x^n_. -> f[n]
```

> ```
> {f[1], f[2], f[3], a, b}
> ```

Comment: Thanks, why add ReleaseHold? I found without it the result is just like what is desired.

Comment: @user55777 Because the "side-effect" of the two hold functions should be neutralized. Please keep in mind that what you see in a *Mathematica* notebook may not what they look like. See my updates in the answer.

Comment: I think the blank-dot syntax is much more preferred in this case, then to fiddle around with Hold and Release…

Comment: @SHuisman Yes, conspicuously!

Comment: @SHuisman But fiddling with hold and release helps  clarify some mechanism for pattern matching, doesn’t it?

Comment: @SHuisman I'd disagree. Blank-dot can have very unintuitive, ambiguous effects since it tries to be "too smart" in some cases and because syntax just gets in the way sometimes. I'd say wrapping _everything_ in `Hold` and then hitting it with a `ReleaseHold` at the end is easier to control and less likely to cause you grief.

Comment: @b3m2a1 Hold would make sense if naturally x^1 would be an outcome of some algorithm. But generally this doesn't happen as it is automatically simplified to just x. So is the output is a mix of x and x^n, i think the blank dot is quite ok to handle these cases.

Answer (score 5):

My recommendation is to look at the `FullForm` of the expression and the replacement.

```
FullForm[{x^1, x^2, x^3, a, b}]

List[x, Power[x,2], Power[x,3], x, b]
```

and

```
FullForm[x^n_]

Power[x, Pattern[n, Blank[]]]
```

This makes it clear that the first element of the list doesn't match the pattern.